# Retrieving Arraylist values in java and store them to javascript array

Tags: java, javascript

I am new in javascript.

How should be `Arraylist` of values in java assigned to `javascript` array?

or what are the ways to retrieve `Arraylist` values in java and store it in `javascript` variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Similar :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592758/how-to-convert-java-arraylist-to-javascript-array?rq=1

Comment: what r u using jsp or servlets?